# Chrome 43 - HTTPS & Wildcard SSL certificate issue

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, https, wildcard

I have a wildcard SSL certificate for a domain and this particular domain is used for a lot of our staging web sites. Therefore whilst we have the wildcard SSL certificate, we don't always setup our staging sites to run over HTTPS because it's not required.

However, ever since Chrome 43 came out at the end of last week (20/05/15), all of our subdomains when viewed in Chrome 43 are being redirected from HTTP to HTTPS. As a result the website does not load because the virtualhost is not setup for SSL and the user receives the message "This webpage is not available".

I realise this error sounds very specific but I can replicate in any Chrome 43 browser on both Mac and PC.

Has anyone come across this issue or know of a fix?

Comment: Maybe you are setting a [HSTS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) header somewhere which includes all subdomains? Even if you had one once and removed it it will still be considered if the browser saw it once.

Comment: It looks as though the domain had been added to the HSTS inclusion list and now Chrome 43 stable is redirecting subdomains to https.

The only issue I have now is that we use sub-subdomains as part of our naming convention for staging websites and as a result the wildcard certificate will only work for single level subdomains.